# Scheme Stream Implementation

Tags: scheme

After working my way through [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) I decided to work though some [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems using scheme. In this particular problem I am trying to generate an infinite stream of integers however I am recieving an error from the MIT Scheme interpreter.

```
;Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This leads me to believe my stream implementation is incorrect however after comparing my code against that in the book I can not find any errors.

```
(define (delay x)
  (lambda ()
    (x)))

(define (force x)
  (x))

(define (cons-stream a b)
  (cons a (delay b)))

(define (car-stream s)
  (car s))

(define (cdr-stream s)
  (force (cdr s)))

(define (integers-starting-from n)
  (cons-stream n (integers-starting-from (+ n 1))))
```

The error occurs when I run the following code:

```
(define n (integers-starting-from 1))
```

Where have I gone wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Chris Jester-Young below I have it working now. The correct implementation of delay and stream are as follows.

```
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((delay expr)
     (lambda ()
       (expr))))

(define-syntax stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((stream a b)
     (cons a (delay b)))))
```

Comment: _Fyi_, the book assumes that both `cons-stream` and `delay` be special forms. Another possibility is to run that code in an evaluator with normal-order evaluation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `delay` and `cons-stream` need to be macros; otherwise your recursive call wouldn't really be delayed.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to fix your code is to embed the recursive call to `integers-starting-from` in a `lambda`:

```
    (define (integers-starting-from n)
      (cons-stream n (lambda () (integers-starting-from (+ n 1)))))
```

This allows you to keep the definitions of `delay` and `cons-stream` as they are in SICP.

Comment: +1: AFAIU this is the only option in a language that does not have macros or lazy evaluation, e.g. Python.

Answer (score -1):

```
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((delay expr)
     (lambda ()
       (expr))))
```

is wrong. Parens around expr will cause an error. Should be:

```
(define-syntax delay
    (syntax-rules ()
        ((delay exp)  (lambda() exp))))
```

Check out https://www.lvguowei.me/post/sicp-goodness-stream-1/ for a version that includes memo-proc.